# 2 Queries work well separately but combined produce a syntax error

Tags: mysql, where-clause

The first query relates to a list of books and authors related to a specific topic and produces the correct result:

```
SELECT BOOK_NUM,
BOOK_TITLE,
BOOK_SUBJECT,
AU_LNAME
FROM BOOK
JOIN WRITES USING (BOOK_NUM)
JOIN AUTHOR USING (AU_ID)
WHERE BOOK_SUBJECT = 'CLOUD'
ORDER BY BOOK_TITLE;
```

The second expands on the theme and also produces the correct result:

```
SELECT BOOK_NUM,
BOOK_TITLE,
BOOK_SUBJECT,
AU_FNAME,
AU_LNAME,
Count(BOOK_TITLE) AS `NUM BOOKS BY AUTHOR`
FROM BOOK
JOIN WRITES USING (BOOK_NUM)
JOIN AUTHOR USING (AU_ID)
GROUP BY BOOK_NUM, AU_ID
ORDER BY `NUM BOOKS BY AUTHOR`,
AU_LNAME;
```

When I combine the two it produces a syntax error at WHERE BOOK_SUBJECT = 'CLOUD':

```
SELECT BOOK_NUM,
BOOK_TITLE,
BOOK_SUBJECT,
AU_FNAME,
AU_LNAME,
Count(BOOK_TITLE) AS `NUM BOOKS BY AUTHOR`
FROM BOOK
JOIN WRITES USING (BOOK_NUM)
JOIN AUTHOR USING (AU_ID)
GROUP BY BOOK_NUM, AU_ID
WHERE BOOK_SUBJECT = 'CLOUD'
ORDER BY `NUM BOOKS BY AUTHOR`, 
AU_LNAME,
BOOK_TITLE;
```

No matter where I place it, I get the same error and if I remove it, the code runs.  What do I need to do to fix this? I need this where clause to be included. Thank you in advance for helping me out.

Comment: Pay close attention to the order of the various conditions in the [`SELECT` documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html).

Comment: ^ You have to have `WHERE` above `GROUP BY`. Another thing to look into might be `HAVING`: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp

Comment: And if you're still struggling, see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question. Try to reference some documentation on the order of expressions...

Try the following code, where we moved the `WHERE` statement appropriately.

```
SELECT 
BOOK_NUM,
BOOK_TITLE,
BOOK_SUBJECT,
AU_FNAME,
AU_LNAME,
Count(BOOK_TITLE) AS `NUM BOOKS BY AUTHOR`

FROM BOOK
JOIN WRITES USING (BOOK_NUM)
JOIN AUTHOR USING (AU_ID)

WHERE BOOK_SUBJECT = 'CLOUD'

GROUP BY BOOK_NUM, AU_ID

ORDER BY `NUM BOOKS BY AUTHOR`, 
AU_LNAME,
BOOK_TITLE;
```

Comment: It worked.  Thank you very much!  I am very new to SQL, only been coding for a few weeks.   Thanks for the reference, I will definitely check it out.

Comment: Welcome to SQL, and to programming. If this answer helped you, please consider marking it as "correct" and upvoting if you think it would be useful to other users. This ensures that your question is closed so the community can continue to grow and learn :)

Comment: Thanks Jerry. I am able to upvote but I have a reputation of less than 15 so it's not  showing....

Comment: Don't sweat it. Welcome to programming - SO is a great resource. You are on a great path forward!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what SQL you're using. Try moving the WHERE clause to above the GROUP BY.

Comment: Thanks,  I am using MYSQL.